# Convert varchar2 to Date ('MM/DD/YYYY') in PL/SQL

Tags: date, plsql, format

I need to convert string from varchar to Date in 'MM/DD/YYYY' format. My input string is '4/9/2013' and my expected output is '04/09/2013'. i.e. 2 digit month, 2 digit date and 4 digit year seperated by'/'

I have below data:
DOJ varchar2(10 Byte)column has '4/9/2013' value.
I am using 'select TO_DATE(DOJ,'MM/DD/YYYY') from EmpTable. But I am getting result as 09-APR-13. I want it in 04/09/2013 format.

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A `DATE` has no format, if just converts to a specific format when you ask the database or application to display it. If you need a specific formatted date, you need to convert from `varchar` to `varchar` instead.

Comment: I need output just in varchar or any datatype.. just it should be like '04/09/2013'in Select query.

Comment: Try `TO_DATE(SUBSTR(DOJ, 1, 11), 'dd/mm/rrrr')` with oracle sql 11g

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Easiest way is probably to convert from a VARCHAR to a DATE; then format it back to a VARCHAR again in the format you want;

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(DOJ,'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM EmpTable;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/503d5/4).

Answer (score 6):

First you convert VARCHAR to DATE and then back to CHAR. I do this almost every day and never found any better way.

```
select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(DOJ,'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY') from EmpTable
```

Answer (score 3):

Example query:

`SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2017-08-23','YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM dual;`

Comment: This need code formatting and an explanation to be a valid answer. I'd suggest you take the [tour] read [answer] and then [edit] your post to make it a good quality one