# How to convert hours in varchar to complete a date variable in pl/sql?

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to add a varchar value to my date variable in a stored procedure.

```
PROCEDURE TEST_CAL
(P_HOURS IN VARCHAR2
,P_DATE IN DATE
)
IS
V_DATE date;
BEGIN
    V_DATE := P_DATE;
END;
```

Now V_DATE's value is 03.10.2022 and P_HOURS's value is '7' and I don't know how to add this value to V_DATE so it's value is 03.10.2022 7am.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert varchar2 to Date ('MM/DD/YYYY') in PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346214/convert-varchar2-to-date-mm-dd-yyyy-in-pl-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a multiple of an hour interval:

```plsql
V_DATE := P_DATE + TO_NUMBER(p_hours) * INTERVAL '1' HOUR;
```

or, use `NUMTODSINTERVAL`:

```plsql
V_DATE := P_DATE + NUMTODSINTERVAL(TO_NUMBER(p_hours), 'HOUR');
```

or, use arithmetic:

```plsql
V_DATE := P_DATE + TO_NUMBER(p_hours) / 24;
```

Even better, pass the hours as a number and not a string:

```plsql
PROCEDURE TEST_CAL(
  P_HOURS IN INTEGER
, P_DATE  IN DATE
)
IS
  V_DATE date;
BEGIN
  V_DATE := P_DATE + p_hours * INTERVAL '1' HOUR;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2GVCKHpD)

Comment: I tried all your solutions but for idk what reason the result always end up being 04.10.2022. It counts like a whole day passes but Im literally just adding 7 hours and event if it shows it as being the 4th it still doesn't shows any hour.

Comment: @DanisOnTheFlux The default format your session is using to convert the date to a string to display it is only showing the date, and not the time, component (but that does not mean that the time component was not set, only that it is not being displayed). You can use `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';` (outside the procedure) to change the default format model for date-to-string conversions or when you print the date use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(v_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));` to explicitly display the time component as well.